# Where find events tracker in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have track event like this.

```
 $('.payment_button').on('click', function() {
        var _this = this;
        ga('send', 'event', 'Payment', 'Payment', 'Payment Checkout', {
            'hitCallback': function() {
                $(_this).parents('form').first().submit();
            }
        });
```

It's worked good, but I don't know where to view results. In google analitics admin I can view my event only in real time events, but after 30 minuts it's removes and I can't view it.

**UPDATE:** [Google Analytics generally updates reports every 24 hour](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009219?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left side of the reports page where the Report Navigation menus is, it's under

Behavior > Events